# ImageResizer adjusting white balance

Tags: imageresizer

Been playing with [StudioJS](https://github.com/nathanaeljones/studiojs) wrapper for [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/). Can ImageResizer adjust the white balance relative to a color? Ultimately, I want the user to be able to click an area in the image that should be white, and the rest of the image adjusts.

I see the Auto Balance functionality that uses the AdvancedFilters plugin, I guess I want to take it a step further.

Comment: Could you let me know what my answer lacks, or mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ImageResizer doesn't current support adjusting relative to a color. However, if you wanted to implement said feature, it would not be difficult.

You could modify AdvancedFilters.cs, inserting an IF statement near line 150, and add support for a new command, such as "&a.white=rrggbb".

Simply provide the RGB values to the LinearLevels class to perform the scaling on the image.
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/29bf1191-47c9-314b-eb8d-bea3f903ac28.htm

If you like the result, and want to share it, send me a pull request on GitHub or e-mail me the code snippet. If it passes testing, it might make it into the next release.

Client side, [you might find this library helpful](http://blog.project-sierra.de/projects/image-color-picker) for selecting a color from an image.

Comment: Thanks for your response, having some issues using the LevelsLinear class to achieve the desired result. I'm not sure how to interpret the  RGB min/max params. I thought I would use the same value for min/max, but that doesn't work too well.

Comment: LevelsLinear accepts input ranges and output ranges for each channel. The min values should probably always be 0. The input max value should probably be the provided value for the corresponding channel, and the output should be 255 (as you're converting the given color to 100% white.

Comment: Thanks for all your help with this, I'll give it a try.